# Pandas read text file with special regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I need to get ad dataframe from files built up like this:

```
MANDT#|#BWKEY#|#BUKRS#|#BWMOD#|#XBKNG#|#MLBWA#|#MLBWV#|#XVKBW
150#|#2000#|#1001#|##|##|##|##|#
150#|#2001#|#1001#|##|##|##|##|#
150#|#2002#|#1001#|##|##|##|##|#
150#|#4000#|#1000#|##|##|##|##|#
150#|#4001#|#1000#|##|##|##|##|#
150#|#4002#|#1000#|##|##|##|##|#
150#|#4003#|#1000#|##|##|##|##|#
150#|#4005#|#1000#|##|##|##|##|#
```

What would be the right python regex for separation (#|#) in read_csv?

Thank´s!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the vertical bar, which has a special meaning, with `\|`

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'#\|#')
print(df)

   MANDT  BWKEY  BUKRS  BWMOD  XBKNG  MLBWA  MLBWV  XVKBW
0    150   2000   1001    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1    150   2001   1001    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2    150   2002   1001    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3    150   4000   1000    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    150   4001   1000    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
5    150   4002   1000    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
6    150   4003   1000    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
7    150   4005   1000    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```